# Is there any way to get the "emailVerified" from my firebase auth user using ''auth REST API''?

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

I'm currently using firebase as my backend webserver , and I used the auth REST API to authenticate users in my app (login using email and password ). My question is I want to know if there is an http request that I can a response by it that includes if the email that logged in is verified or not , I have tried mixing the rest API with the firebase-Auth package but it didn't work .

I just found the "setAccountInfo" endpoint, but for it to work I need the " oobCode " from  the confirmation email that was send to the user and I can't get that automatically, I guess. 
Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: Hi, can you show us what you have tried?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can do that with the [`getAccountInfo`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth#section-get-account-info) endpoint, which returns the following payload (sample from the doc) that contains a `emailVerified` property:

```
{
  "users": [
    {
      "localId": "ZY1rJK0...",
      "email": "user@example.com",
      "emailVerified": false,
      "displayName": "John Doe",
      "providerUserInfo": [
        {
          "providerId": "password",
          "displayName": "John Doe",
          "photoUrl": "http://localhost:8080/img1234567890/photo.png",
          "federatedId": "user@example.com",
          "email": "user@example.com",
          "rawId": "user@example.com",
          "screenName": "user@example.com"
        }
      ],
      "photoUrl": "https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/.../photo.jpg",
      "passwordHash": "...",
      "passwordUpdatedAt": 1.484124177E12,
      "validSince": "1484124177",
      "disabled": false,
      "lastLoginAt": "1484628946000",
      "createdAt": "1484124142000",
      "customAuth": false
    }
  ]
}
```

**Sample Request (from the doc, pasted for reference):**

> ```
> curl
> 'https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:lookup?key=[API_KEY]'
> \
> -H 'Content-Type: application/json' --data-binary '{"idToken":"[FIREBASE_ID_TOKEN]"}'
> ```
>
> In the example above, you would replace [API_KEY] with the Web API Key
>   of your Firebase project and [FIREBASE_ID_TOKEN] with the user's
>   Firebase ID token.

---

PS: I've not tried the `setAccountInfo` endpoint you mention at the end of your question, but I think it is used for sending (POST) the verification code received by email (From the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth#section-confirm-email-verification): -> "oobCode: The action code sent to user's email for email verification.")

Comment: i didn't notice the setAccountInfo endPoint exists , it did work  and it gave me all the informations i need , Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

```
import pyrebase
firebaseConfig = {
  "apiKey": "",
  "authDomain": "",
  "projectId": "",
  "storageBucket": "",
  "messagingSenderId": "",
  "appId": "",
  "measurementId": "",
  "databaseURL": ""
}
firebase = pyrebase.initialize_app(firebaseConfig)
auth = firebase.auth()
email= "your Email"
password = "your Password"
login = auth.sign_in_with_email_and_password(email, password)
acc_info=auth.get_account_info(login['idToken'])
if "users" in acc_info:
    if acc_info["users"]:
        for val in acc_info['users']:
            if "emailVerified" in val:
                print(val["emailVerified"])
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).